# Android app is non responsive in Amazon fireTV

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

I have developed an Android app which works well on mobiles and tablets. Recently I have installed it on Amazon fireTV and I see that some screens are not responding for touch events. I tried using the physical remote and the Amazon fireTV remote app but no use.

I have a screen with list of videos and I want to go through each of them but I couldn't do it. I have read that most (75%) of the Android apps work fine on Amazon fireTV. Do I have to develop my app using any Amazon SDK to make it work on TV? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

**NOTE:** Posted this question in Android Enthusiasts but I got to know it's off-topic there, so I'm posting it here.

Comment: Amazon's OS isn't exactly this same what Androi OS is so you should develope app directly for Amazon SDK.

Comment: It's actually not that different. I got my Android TV app to work and be approved for Amazon Fire TV with just a few changes. And with the new version of the Fire OS, they have actually deprecated their own examples and just point you to Google.

Answer (score 1):

In order to work well, there are some things you need to do differently for TV apps (whether for Amazon Fire TV or Android TV). You can find help for navigation here: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html

There is also helpful information here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/overview/developing-apps-and-games-for-amazon-fire-tv